# Change Background Color of iframe

Tags: html

I'm trying to change the background color of this iframe element. I don't have any coding experience but I'm hoping someone can help me get the background color to this hex code #f9f9f8 instead of the default white.

```html
<p align="center">
  <iframe src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/webmasters/?downpayment=&amp;homevalue=&amp;loanamount=&amp;interestrate=&amp;loanterm=30&amp;propertytax=&amp;pmi=1&amp;homeinsurance=&amp;monthlyhoa=0" 
    style="width: 110%; height: 1210px; border: 0;"></iframe>
</p>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

I've tried this based on what I've googled and a mashup of another calculator on the site but the background didn't change:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <p style="background-color:#f9f9f8;">
  <br>
  <iframe src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/webmasters/?downpayment=&amp;homevalue=&amp;loanamount=&amp;interestrate=&amp;loanterm=30&amp;propertytax=&amp;pmi=1&amp;homeinsurance=&amp;monthlyhoa=0" 
    style="width: 110%; height: 1210px; border: 0; background-color:#f9f9f8;"></iframe>
  </p>
</div>
```

The other calculator that I used to get to ^^:

```html
<div style="width:260px; text-align:center;">
  <p style="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <a href="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/free-tools/calc/mortgage-calculator-logo.png" alt="MortgageCalculator.org.">
    </a>
    <br>
    <iframe src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/free-tools/calc/?value=400000&down=80000&amount=320000&rate=4&years=30&pmi=0.7&insurance=1500&taxes=3000&hoa=0&cur=$" 
       frameborder="0" width="260px" height="400" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/free-tools/">
      <font color="#000000">www.MortgageCalculator.org</font>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change the background color of the iframe, because it's going to show the contents of the src, which will overwrite the background.

Comment: technically an iframe is an independent HTML page but occupying part of a parent page. The word to remember here is **independent**.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess what confused me was that the last one let me change the background color and I was hoping that the version I wanted to use would let me do that as well, but it sounds like it's not possible. Appreciate your responses!

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more. The same is true for the `align` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this code ,here I am using this [Mortgage Calculator](https://mortagecalulator.com/) website for embedding link. This will definitely help you to change background color.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="https://mortagecalulator.com/">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
  x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: As a note: This will not change the background color in the iframe itself, but of the iframe element. There is not way to interact with the content of an iframe, since it is a sandboxed envoirnment